# Java - Asteroids - acceleration in two dimensions

Tags: java, rotation, game-physics

I am currently writing Asteroids for extra credit in my computer science class, following a very loose guide that provided some starter code. I have a ship and I can use key presses to change its position. The starter code provided a method of drawing the ship based on a Point position. I was then given this

```
public void accelerate(double acceleration) {
    pull.x += (acceleration * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation)));
    pull.y += (acceleration * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation)));
}
```

How am I supposed to implement this with position? I can increase both position.x and position.y, but how exactly am I supposed to use this method? Also, can I implement acceleration for turning? There is a variable rotation that is supposed to go from `0` to `360`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how to answer this without seeing more of your code, but make sure that you understand how position, velocity, and acceleration are related. Acceleration, over time *t*, equals the derivative of velocity (dv/dt). Velocity equals the derivative of position (dx/dt). It also works the other way around with integration. Acceleration and Velocity are vectors, meaning they have magnitude *and* direction. You need to change the position based on the velocity, and the velocity based on the acceleration. Does this help at all?

Comment: I'm going to have to learn more about acceleration, but you provided a very concise description of what I need to do. Thank you.